# Setting up my website I had hosted by an online server Provider in XAMPP

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

some time ago I've had a wordpress website hosted by an online server Provider. I cancelled the service, and wanted to set up the Website locally via XAMPP. Therefore, I've copied my files in htdocs & imported the database in phpMyAdmin. My Question now is how to name this database? I always get the notice "Error establishing a database connection". I would be really thankful for your ideas.

Comment: Go to `wp-config` file and change them according to your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have implemented the same in wp-config.php

```
define( 'DB_NAME',     'imported_database_name_here' );
define( 'DB_USER',     'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'DB_HOST',     'localhost' );
```

password should be blank for default installation of xampp.